# WordPress menu Width wrong

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

**I have this site 
http://beautyworldinternet.co.il/
look in the menu and you can see that its have 2 row 
I need it be 1 row 
how can I do it?**

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css file change the padding from this

```
 #main-navigation .menu li a {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #383838;
padding: 11px 24px 0 24px;
margin: 0 0;
min-height: 27px;
top: 0;
display: block;
border-right: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
}
```

to this

```
 #main-navigation .menu li a {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #383838;
padding: 11px 13px 0 13px;
margin: 0 0;
min-height: 27px;
top: 0;
display: block;
border-right: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
}
```